# Are there color materials present

Tags: materials

Im much confused with the node editor. I want to know are there any ready made material with addon or website directly i can just apply (gold, silver, cloths, metallic etc) with material and textures

Comment: The Matlib VX has. https://sites.google.com/site/aleonserra/home/scripts/matlib-vx-5-6

Comment: And worth a look at http://blendermada.com